# Выпадающий список из базы в динамической таблице

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Сделал выпадающий список из базы

```
<?include_once('db.php') ?>
<?
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `gj`";
    $result_select = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
    echo "<select name = '1234'>";
        while($object = mysqli_fetch_object($result_select)){
    echo "<option value = '$object->cyr_name' > $object->lat_name </option>";}
    echo "</select>";
    ?>
```

Он работает, но хочу поместить его в динамическую таблицу

```js
class selectClass {
  constructor(id) {
    var obj = document.createElement("select");
    var option1 = document.createElement("option");
    var option2 = document.createElement("option");
    var option3 = document.createElement("option");
    option1.innerHTML = "option1";
    option2.innerHTML = "option2";
    option3.innerHTML = "option3";
    obj.appendChild(option1);
    obj.appendChild(option2);
    obj.appendChild(option3);
    obj.id = id;
    return obj;
  }
}
             
function test(){
  var table = document.getElementById('mytable');
  var tr = document.createElement("tr");

  table.appendChild(tr);
  for(var i=0; i < 31; i++) {
    var td = document.createElement("td");
    var select = new selectClass(i);
    alert(select);
    td.appendChild(select);
    tr.appendChild(td);
  }
}
window.onload = function(){
  //document.getElementById('clicker').onclick = function(){test()}
  document.getElementById('clicker').onclick = function(){test()}
}
```

На js получилось сделать выпадающий список в динамической таблице, но не получается связать, как это реализовать?